# Coverting dates on the same pd column that are in different format (Excel float + dd/mm/yy) into Python dates

Tags: python

I am really struggling to convert two different types of dates on the same pd dataframe into python dates.

This is the type of dates I have:

```
1   44859   
2   7/12/22 
3   6/12/22
```

Here is the code I have tried so far but it still results in NaT for the Excel format dates (integers that represent the actual date).

```
import pandas as pd
import xlrd


# define function to convert Excel float dates to Python dates using xlrd
def excel_to_date(excel_date):
    return xlrd.xldate_as_datetime(excel_date, 0).date()  # assuming 0-based indexing

# convert Excel float dates to Python dates using the defined function
df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: excel_to_date(x) if isinstance(x, float) else x)

# convert remaining dates to Python dates using to_datetime()
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], errors='coerce')

print(df)
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: What type of date is  `44859` in this case?

Comment: That's literally how Excel stores dates.  That's  integer days since 1/1/1970.

Comment: Would you be able to help?